When I move the bones and they bend, they can't bend where they can do it clearly
I have this flower that I added an armature to to bend the stem and it works fine. But when I use the control bone to bend it to a certain point, it's like the skeleton says that it can't get to that pose. Even though it looks it should be able to, it refuses to.
The Armature:

The control bone(top) and the one with the IK Constraint to make the other bones move when that one moves:

Good bend:

The issue when I move it a little bit more to the side:

The armature:


I don't know why it bugs, maybe a calculation problem, that said why do you use such a long chain? you could use only several bones and segment them.

I wan using less bones, but I wanted to make the mesh look smother when bending so I added more bones, but I'm sure the problem would still be there :(

have you tried to segment your bones? It is made to avoid tens of bones

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

It may be a problem of calculation, but instead of using tens of bones, maybe just use several and segment them?
First thing create an armature with for example 3 bones, display them as B-Bones (if you want to make them thicker use AltCtrlShiftS in Edit mode), you don't need to display them as B-Bones but it will make the segmentation visible:

Select the 3 bones in Edit mode then in the Bone panel > Bendy Bones > Segments > press AltLMB on the value, type 3 (or whatever segmentation value you want) and Enter:

Switch to Pose mode and enable the Auto IK option:

Select the last bone and move it:

Also you can set the Ease In and Out values to make it rounder:


it's much easier?

I'll try that thanks
